# Soft or more euphemistic way of saying "suffer"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

One word I can think of is "bear". Any other words for it? I hate the idea of repeating the same word again and again. I want to use it for trivial things which make your life inconvenient but not hell.

Comment: Try *endure*: "Some things we have to endure."

Comment: *To put up with* can also be *abide*.

Comment: Another option (with roughly the same meaning as _endure_) is _tolerate_.

Comment: How do you vote on a comment?  Many comments I see best all the answers.  I'd click endure but I don't seem to have those magic powers yet (and if they're awarded, I'll probably never obtain)

Comment: @user116032 I am not sure about what minimum reputation is needed to vote on a comment but once you achieve it, you just need to hover your cursor over the comment of your interest and you will see a grey colored upward pointing arrow(vote up) icon on the top left corner of the block(sort of?) which would turn into maroon color once you click on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Struggle with
Agonise over
Contend with
Deal with
Trouble over

Answer (score 1):

I particularly like *deal with*, proposed by @MDMcDMD.  Here's a way to use it:

> My mother-in-law has her arthritis to **deal with**.

Alternatively:

**We all have our troubles**

is a nice way of complaining.

Here's a nice made-up noun my German spouse invented once:

> ... the tougheties of life

Answer (score 1):

How about **overcome challenges**?

Comment: No, your partly-philosophical answer is not relevant. I need to highlight the mild pain.

Comment: I suggest you remove euphemistic from the question title. From http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism : *a mild or pleasant word or phrase that is used instead of one that is unpleasant or offensive*

Comment: why? what's wrong with that? I really need a 'mild' word. Is there any other word I could use instead of euphemistic?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Anyone who has overcome a challenge knows that there's some mild pain involved. Arthritis can be challenging. Aerobic workouts or hikes can be challenging. Bad traffic can be challenging, etc. No pain, no gain.

Comment: Some examples: A person standing in a slow-moving queue for a long time or inconveniences caused to a person when a train he was travelling in, comes to halt due to some technical issue or a person travelling with a crying kid sitting nearby in a plane. It's not exactly suffering maybe just they're just a victim of misfortune. It's not challenging either :-)

Comment: Not sure everyone agrees with your definition of challenging :-) http://www.consumeraffairs.com/news/holiday-travel-likely-to-be-even-more-challenging-this-year-110614.html

Comment: hahaha, thanks so much for the link. I take my words back regarding your answer, it's completely relevant. I found some more usable words(hassle, complication etc.) in that link.

Answer (score 1):

"Withstand" or just "stand" : "She withstood the loss..."

Answer (score 0):

ache

abide

endure (that reminds me of a Revenge episode :))

agonise (not really softer)

sustain (as in sustain an injury)

hurt

I don't know if the one you are looking for is in this list.